# Xamarin Form Receive Image from other app

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, android-intent, share

I'm developing a Xamarin Form app for Android and iOS. I want to receive an image from another app, like Whatsapp or Text Messaging, etc., that when you select an image and click Share, my app appears on the share list options, then select my app, and on my app present a Preview of the image.

I was looking on different posts, but I didn't found a good example of how receive an image on my app, special in iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For Android**:

define the `IntentFilter` in your `MainActivity` :

```
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/MyTheme", MainLauncher = true,LaunchMode =LaunchMode.SingleTask)]
[IntentFilter(new string[] { Intent.ActionSend },Categories = new string[] { Intent.CategoryDefault },DataMimeType = "image/*")]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
  protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {   
         //if your activity LaunchMode not SingleTask or SingleTop,when you receive the share image,it will trigger in the OnCreate method

         Android.Net.Uri imageUri = (Android.Net.Uri)intent.GetParcelableExtra(Intent.ExtraStream);
         .....
    }

  //if lanch mode is singletask or singletop,it will trigger in the OnNewIntent method(This is recommended)
  protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        base.OnNewIntent(intent);
        Android.Net.Uri imageUri = (Android.Net.Uri)intent.GetParcelableExtra(Intent.ExtraStream);
    }


}
```

**For ios**

You should create a `share extension`,then add the reference to your ios project,refer to [the similar case](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/177382/how-to-implement-share-extension-to-xamarin-forms-ios-project)